# Is there a way to crossfade multiple clips of one track in one click with Adobe Audition?

Tags: automation, volume, adobe

I've got a project which has some background music clips which I'd like to crossfade, I usually make it by taking each clip and dragging it into the previous one a little, but I have to be very careful to keep the same amount of time or percentage of the total. I'd like to do it automatically, in one click and standarized... do you know how to do it??

Thank you very much!!!

To clarify, that's my scenario:
[image]
And I want to reach that other in a click and in an homogeneic way
[image]